# Using React-Three-Fiber

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber

I'm currently using React Three Fiber to simply render a sun and the earth orbiting it to test it out. However after I added code to apply textures to the respective spheres every time I run the development server for testing, the spheres fail to render. I've tried looking for people with the same issue and have not had any luck. Here is my code for the program.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { Canvas, useFrame, useLoader } from 'react-three-fiber'
import { TextureLoader } from 'three/src/loaders/TextureLoader'
import { useTexture } from "@react-three/drei";

function Sun(props) {
  const [colorMap] = useTexture(['Sun_texture.jpg'])
  const mesh = useRef()
  const [state, setState] = useState({ isHovered: false, isActive: false })
  useFrame((state) => {
    const time = state.clock.getElapsedTime()
    mesh.current.rotation.z = 0
    mesh.current.rotation.x = 0
    mesh.current.rotation.y = time / 5
  })

  return (
    <mesh
      {...props}
      ref={mesh}
      
      scale={[1, 1, 1]}
      onPointerOver={(e) => setState({ ...state, isHovered: true })}
      onPointerOut={(e) => setState({ ...state, isHovered: false })}>
      <sphereGeometry args={[0.5, 100, 100]} map={colorMap} />
      <meshStandardMaterial map={colorMap} transparent={true} emissive={'#444444'} emissiveIntensity={0.3}/>
    </mesh>
  )
}

function Earth(props) {
  const mesh = useRef()
  const [state, setState] = useState({ isHovered: false, isActive: false })
  const [colorMap] = useTexture(['Earth_texture.jpg'])
  useFrame((state) => {
    const time = state.clock.getElapsedTime()
    mesh.current.position.x = 4 * Math.sin(time / 10)
    mesh.current.position.y = 0
    mesh.current.position.z = 4 * Math.cos(time / 10)
    mesh.current.rotation.z = 0
    mesh.current.rotation.x = 0
    mesh.current.rotation.y = time / 2
  })

  return (
    <mesh
      {...props}
      ref={mesh}
      scale={[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]}
      onPointerOver={(e) => setState({ ...state, isHovered: true })}
      onPointerOut={(e) => setState({ ...state, isHovered: false })}>
      <sphereBufferGeometry args={[0.5, 40, 40]} map={colorMap} />
      <meshStandardMaterial map={colorMap} />
    </mesh>
  )
}



export default function App() {
  return (
    <Canvas camera={{position: [0, 2, 8]}}>
      <Sun position={[0, 0, 0]} />
      <Earth position={[3, 0, 0]} />
      <ambientLight intensity={0.01}/>
      <pointLight position={[0, 0, 0]}/>
      
      <spotLight position={[1.5, 0, 0]} distance={4}/>
      <spotLight position={[-1.5, 0, 0]} distance={4}/>
      <spotLight position={[0, 0, -1.5]} distance={4}/>
      <spotLight position={[0, 0, 1.5]} distance={4}/>
      <spotLight position={[0, 1.5, 0]} distance={4}/>
      <spotLight position={[0, -1.5, 0]} distance={4}/>
    </Canvas>
  )
}
```

Specifically the texture portions are the issue, but I can't find anything wrong with it.

```
const [colorMap] = useTexture(['Sun_texture.jpg'])
...
<sphereGeometry args={[0.5, 100, 100]} map={colorMap} />
<meshStandardMaterial map={colorMap} transparent={true} emissive={'#444444'} emissiveIntensity={0.3}/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your `<Earth>` component in a `<Suspense>` because it needs to load a texture so the way to do it is to wait for it to load using suspense.

You can specify an object to show while it is loading by doing

```
<suspense fallback={<loadingComponent />} >
```

so this would give you something like :

```js
import React, { useRef, useState, Suspense } from 'react'
import { Canvas, useFrame, useLoader } from 'react-three-fiber'
import { TextureLoader } from 'three/src/loaders/TextureLoader'
import { useTexture } from "@react-three/drei";

function Sun(props) {
  const [colorMap] = useTexture(['Sun_texture.jpg'])
  const mesh = useRef()
  const [state, setState] = useState({ isHovered: false, isActive: false })
  useFrame((state) => {
    const time = state.clock.getElapsedTime()
    mesh.current.rotation.z = 0
    mesh.current.rotation.x = 0
    mesh.current.rotation.y = time / 5
  })

  return (
    <mesh
      {...props}
      ref={mesh}
      
      scale={[1, 1, 1]}
      onPointerOver={(e) => setState({ ...state, isHovered: true })}
      onPointerOut={(e) => setState({ ...state, isHovered: false })}>
      <sphereGeometry args={[0.5, 100, 100]} map={colorMap} />
      <meshStandardMaterial map={colorMap} transparent={true} emissive={'#444444'} emissiveIntensity={0.3}/>
    </mesh>
  )
}

function Earth(props) {
  const mesh = useRef()
  const [state, setState] = useState({ isHovered: false, isActive: false })
  const [colorMap] = useTexture(['Earth_texture.jpg'])
  useFrame((state) => {
    const time = state.clock.getElapsedTime()
    mesh.current.position.x = 4 * Math.sin(time / 10)
    mesh.current.position.y = 0
    mesh.current.position.z = 4 * Math.cos(time / 10)
    mesh.current.rotation.z = 0
    mesh.current.rotation.x = 0
    mesh.current.rotation.y = time / 2
  })

  return (
    <mesh
      {...props}
      ref={mesh}
      scale={[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]}
      onPointerOver={(e) => setState({ ...state, isHovered: true })}
      onPointerOut={(e) => setState({ ...state, isHovered: false })}>
      <sphereBufferGeometry args={[0.5, 40, 40]} map={colorMap} />
      <meshStandardMaterial map={colorMap} />
    </mesh>
  )
}



export default function App() {
  return (
    <Canvas camera={{position: [0, 2, 8]}}>
      <Sun position={[0, 0, 0]} />
      <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
      <Earth position={[3, 0, 0]} />
      </Suspense>
      <ambientLight intensity={0.01}/>
      <pointLight position={[0, 0, 0]}/>
      
      <spotLight position={[1.5, 0, 0]} distance={4}/>
      <spotLight position={[-1.5, 0, 0]} distance={4}/>
      <spotLight position={[0, 0, -1.5]} distance={4}/>
      <spotLight position={[0, 0, 1.5]} distance={4}/>
      <spotLight position={[0, 1.5, 0]} distance={4}/>
      <spotLight position={[0, -1.5, 0]} distance={4}/>
    </Canvas>
  )
}
```

You can find cool stuff and examples about react-three-fiber on codeSandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/search?refinementList%5Bnpm_dependencies.dependency%5D%5B0%5D=%40react-three%2Ffiber&page=1&configure%5BhitsPerPage%5D=12&query=

tell me if you need more precision.